# Laravel - Not getting correct data from database (issue with czech characters)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have some issue with czech letters `čřžýš` etc. I am tryig to run simple foreach loop to display data from database (tea category) but after first correct output (Darjeeling), I get this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

The problem seems to be with with letters. When I try this in foreach loop `$tea->categories->first()`

I get this result:

> {"id":1,"tea_id":1,"name":"Darjeeling","created_at":"2016-09-18 13:56:49","updated_at":"2016-09-18 13:56:49"}{"id":5,"tea_id":4,"name":"\u010dern\u00e9","created_at":"2016-09-18 13:56:49","updated_at":"2016-09-18 13:56:49"}

Instead of `černé` which is correctly in database, I get `\u010dern\u00e9`.

Anoyone knows how to fix it pls? I have `<meta charset="utf-8">` already in my blade template.

Comment: Please show your foreach loop code.

Comment: It's up there. Only this:

foreach ($teas as $tea) 
        {
            echo $tea->categories->first();
        }

Comment: The loop trowing an error was:

foreach ($teas as $tea) { echo $tea->categories->first()->name; }

Comment: The error says you're trying to read an object property from something which is not an object. My guess is that one of the teas has no categories, therefore `$tea->categories->first()` does not return an object. Therefore `->name` on this non-object is throwing you the error.